# How do I sniff traffic from a vm using another vm using Wireshark in the same network?

Tags: wireshark, sniffing, vmware

I have setup 2 virtual machines.

1. Ubuntu16.04 - 10.10.130.10
2. Kali-rolling with wireshark 2.2.7 - 10.10.130.13

Both have access to the internet.

I'm trying to understand how the flows look like when I do certain pentest activities on 10.10.130.10 but I keep getting ARP Broadcast messages for like 9 lines in Wireshark before it stops printing.

I have enabled promiscuous mode on all my interfaces.

I can see traffic if I:

A. ping from 10.10.130.13 to 10.10.130.10 or vice versa
B. ping www.google.com

Am I missing some more procedure to make this work?

Comment: This is not a security question but a networking question. It also has little to do with Kali (removed). Your vm network is set up like a switch, which limits what each VM can see.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable promiscuous mode on your vSwitch too.

You don't mention the hypervisor you are using but in ESXi it is as simple as editing the vswitch and under advanced options enable promiscuous mode. Make sure that both VM's are on the same vSwitch (probably makes sense to make sure that they are the only VM's on this switch) and everything should work.